# protected keyword

Tags: .net

I seem not to understand the protected access modifier

From reading the msdn, it seems that I can declare a property PROTECTED in class A.

Have class B inherit from class A and then access the property.

My issue is when I instantiate class B I cannot access class A protected method. Psuedo code below

```
class a
{
protected int steve {get;set}
}
class b:a
{}

console app
private foo = new class b();
foo.steve = 3;
```

I understand this code will not compile, I am looking for the theory on why i cannot access steve from an instantiated version of B. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`protected` members can be accessed inside derived classes, but for others, it is like `private`.
This means:
You can access `steve` in a member of `a` or `b` or any other derived type. But you cannot access `steve` from the outside.

Comment: Chose this question as the answer because it explained how the protected keyword was working and told me why I couldn't use it the way I thought. thank you all for taking your time to read my question and answer

Answer (score 4):

You are accessing it from outside of class b. This would work because it is being accessed from inside class b.

```
class a
{
protected int steve {get;set}
}

class b:a
{
public void foo() {
  steve = 4;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Protected` is similar to private in that the class that declares the method, variable, etc. can use it, but it exposes the method or variable to be used in subclasses as well.

Answer (score 1):

"b" can see protected members of "a" because "b" is "a", however when trying to call "b", you can't see "a" protected members.  You can experiment with this by making "steve" public and then changing the modifiers on the "get" and "set" on the property for different results.  i.e.  You can only set the property from "b", but can get it from anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The `protected` modifiers allows derived classes to access the member within the confines of their declaration.  To the outside world `protected` is no different than `private`

```
class a {
  protected int steve {get;set}
}
class b : a {
  void Example() {
    steve = 42; // legal. Access protected within the declaration
  }
}

class Program {
  public static void Main() {
    b local = new b();
    local.steve = 13; // Error! Outside b`s declaration steve is effectively private
  }
}
```